# Do work on WCF service without blocking mobile app

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to get my WCF service to do a "heavy" task without making the mobile app wait for it to finish. When I sync my app, I want it to do this heavy task on its own, allowing the user to continue doing whatever they want in the app.

I have a feeling this is related to Tasks and async methods, but i'm a little confused how it works. I wrote some test code to try and figure out a good way to handle it, but im a little bewildered by my results so far.

```
public async void AsyncTest()
{
    SendReport();

    Debug.WriteLine("created");

}

private async Task<bool> SendReport()
{
    MyHeavyCode();
    Debug.WriteLine("Code Finished");
    return true;
}
```

when i run this code, I would expect the console to print out before the `MyHeavyCode()` method finishes doing its work as it isn't awaited, however the "Code Finished" line appears, then the report the heavy code generates, and finally the "created" message.

It was my understanding that `await` would cause it to pause, so why is it occuring this way?

for clarity, what im trying to achieve is the heavy lifting to be completed on its own, without forcing the user to wait.

Comment: You don't have an `await` in there, and without seeing the definitions of `SendReport` and `MyHeavyCode` it is going to be difficult to understand what is going on.

Comment: @PeterMorris myheavycode just generates a pdf with migradoc, sendreport is already in my question. Within the `MyHeavyCode` method, there are no more async methods or tasks, just a few object builds and database requests.

Comment: `MyHeavyCode` should be returning a `Task` that you `await` on. `SendReport` should also return a `Task` that you can `await`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to await all of your async methods. Addtionally if `MyHeavyWork` is a CPU bound process you'll need to kick it off in parallel. Your `await` should be extended all the way from `MyHeavyWork` throughout the WCF service and ending on the event handler used to kick off the whole process. I've removed `Task<bool>` in favor of just a `Task` since it didn't apear to be a relevant return type.

```
public async void AsyncTest()
{
    await SendReport();

    Debug.WriteLine("created");

}

private async Task SendReport()
{
    await MyHeavyCodeIO(); //IO bound
    await Task.Run(() => MyHeavyCodeCPU()); //CPU bound
    Debug.WriteLine("Code Finished");
}

private async MyHeavyCodeIO()
{
    //Heavy work...
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}

private async MyHeavyCodeCPU()
{
    //Heavy work...
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: I thought that the awaiting keyword would make the system pause and wait for the task to finish?

Comment: @Takarii yes but in an asynchronous way. The body of the method with aill pause at the `await` keyword but the program as a whole will continue and be responsive. Basically the method call will be paused but that will not block any other method calls.

Comment: ok, so in your example above, once it hits `await MyHeavyCodeIO()` it will print "Code finished" immediatly afterwards, while still running the code in the background?

Comment: @Takarii No `await` will pause execution of the method body. This allows async code to be written in an synchronous way. In the example `AsyncTest` would be an event handler, such as a button click. That would spawn the `SendReport Task` asynchronously. Now the important part is that after `SendReport` is fired a user can freely execute `AsyncTest` again and send another report or the user could interact with any other control, even if `SendReport` hasn't finished.